# How to use <source> tag in v-img Vuetify.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to use webp img to instead jpg or png img. Some browsers may not support the webp img, so we use the html tag < source > to do like this, to make sure there is at least a jpg img.

```
<picture>
    <source srcset="good.webp" type="image/webp">
    <img src="fallback.jpg" alt="">
</picture>
```

However, I don't know how to use the same method in the < v-img > Vuetify.js. Does somebody know how to wrap the < source > tag in < v-img >, or any other ways to do the same thing? (webp img 1st, jpg 2nd)

Answer (score 1):

Vuetify's `<v-img>` doesn't create an `<img>` it sets the background of a div to the source that is provided, therefore you cannot use the `<picture>` or `<source>` tag inside it.